# Azure Application Gateway - How to control traffic for different application

Tags: azure, cloud, terraform, azure-application-gateway, azure-load-balancer

I am creating an application gateway and that will be a single point of entry for my multi tenant application. That means I will have multiple application request on this application gateway and then I need to redirect to backend pool. If I will have one application A deployed in app service A then it will listen at port 80 of app gateway. Similar if I have another application, I can expose it using similar way on different port. How can I achieve it. I tried creating multiple rules but not working.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you want multiple app services, each on a potentially different port, to be served by a single application gateway. And it sounds possible you might want to make requests to that application gateway on different port. Sound right?

If so, then what you need to do is something along these lines:

1. Set up a backend pool for each app service.
2. Set up an HTTP setting for each backend pool, specifying port, session affinity, protocol, etc. - This will be the port that your App Service takes requests on.
3. Create a front end IP configuration to expose a public and/or private IP address
4. Create a listener for each app service, and port that you want to support. This will be the port you want the client requests to use. You can do two listeners per service to allow 80 & 443 (HTTP & HTTPS) traffic, for example.
5. Create a rule to connect each listener to its backend pool and HTTP setting combination
6. Optional - set up health probes that target monitoring endpoints based on an URL and a specific HTTP setting entry

Comment: Hi, I have a simillar situation. However I have one listerner (port 443) with multiple/wildcard. The problem is setting up Rules. How can I set a rule to point to one listener with two http-settings? (I have two apps which are using two different ports so I have satup two HTTP settings, one for each app)